# Continuous load with wireless charger

Tags: power, led, pcb, charger, wireless-charging

I have a wireless charger module as seen in the picture and I'm trying to use it to power those tiny wireless LEDs (also on the picture)

The components work properly, as the charger can charge my phone, and it also is phisically capable to power the LEDs.

But when I place the LEDs in the range of the coil, they are only blinking (with around 1Hz) and they are not on continously.

I believe it's because of the (QI?) charging protocol, and these pulses are to check if a load is in range, and once it is, it starts to steadily deliver power (I could confirm this by placing the phone on the coil, it started charging and placing the LEDs close by gave a steady light). But it seems like that the tiny LEDs are not big enough load or missing the logic to signal back and trigger the charging by themselves.

My question is, is there a way to modify/trick this circuit somehow to always steadily deliver wireless power regardless if a load is in range or not?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> *My question is, is there a way to modify/trick this circuit somehow to
> always steadily deliver wireless power regardless if a load is in
> range or not?*

Been there, tried it and concluded that, the best way to make LEDs (attached to a small bobbin inductor and tuning capacitor) glow at any reasonable distance is to scrap the QI coil and make your own coil and driver.

So, my coil and driver take about 15 watts from a 12 volt power supply and can illuminate LEDs up to 16 inches away (at which point the LEDs fail to glow). The coil is a 10 inch square made from thickish copper having a cross sectional area of about 4 sq mm.

The transmit coil needs to be accurately tuned and, I chose to drive it from a bench oscillator and specialist GaN MOSFET H-bridge. This fulfilled what my objectives were but, your objectives may be different. Anyway, I wouldn't recommend going down the Qi route unless you can use something like an external load that can communicate back to the charger and demand that it supplies more power.

Of course if you didn't realize that `those tiny wireless LEDs` also incorporated a tuning capacitor, then you might not have realized that the Qi coil's magnetic field needs to match the resonant frequency for those tiny LEDs. It's unlikely that they did of course.

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that they were lit up properly during the "phone trick" mean that the coil matches the resonant frequency (or at least good enough match)?

Comment: No, unfortunately not; just fairly close proximity and overwhelming magnetic field (despite being at the wrong frequency) would force a few tens of microamps into the LED and illuminate it. If you want things to work at a reasonable distance you need them to be tuned to the transmit frequency. If you have an oscilloscope you should be able to measure that.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to modify/trick this circuit somehow to always steadily deliver wireless power regardless if a load is in range or not?

The short answer is "No".

> I could confirm this by placing the phone on the coil, it started charging and placing the LEDs close by gave a steady light

There you go! Always use your phone first to drive the LEDs!

Joking aside, your LEDs are not designed to be driven with a Qi charger, apparently. Because Qi is not a simple wireless charging technology as it employs several complex things such as handshake and power adjustment *(For example, your phone periodically sends data packets to the charger so the charger can adjust the output power level)*. Qi also allows the detection of unwanted random metal objects so the charger doesn't send full power (or any power) in case of the presence of such a thing.

If the only thing you want is to drive the LEDs then you can make your own wireless charger with an oscillator, a bridge (half or full, for your taste), and a resonant tank.

Comment: I see, thanks! Do you perhaps have any tips or resources that describe how to make my own wireless charger?

Comment: @Razero this is out of your main question's scope. There are numerous resources and example circuits online. One main thing is that for maximum and most efficient power transfer you need to know what frequency your LEDs are tuned to. Good luck.